# Swift issue with TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController and a lapTableViewController. I based all of my information on a tutorial besides creating the array in ViewController and calling it in lapTableViewController.

I put the code for lapTableViewController. I can't figure out what I'm missing because nothing is showing on the TableView. Let me know if you need more info/code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return newTA.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! lapTableCell

    //Configure the Cell:
    cell.numberLabel!.text = newLA[indexPath.row]
    cell.timeLabel!.text = newTA[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    //Return the number of sections:
    return 1
}

//Hides Status Bar
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Edit your question specifying the problem.. what it does? crashes? doesn't show? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry I originally wrote the issue and messed up the formatting and must've deleted that part. Just edited it! @Andrea

Comment: How do you create the tableview? Have you set  its delegate and datasource? Are there items in the array?

Comment: Do you have a data source for the table view?

Comment: @Paulw11 I created the tableView in the storyboard and then made the lapTableViewController. You actually just helped me solve it. My lapTableViewController and Storyboard weren't linked. Simple issue I just skipped right over. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recorded here as an answer for the sake of completeness:

The storyboard view had to be linked to the class that inherits from `UITableViewController` (in this case `lapTableViewController`)